# GeoNetwork: How to reset the admin password?

Tags: geonetwork

I am unable to log on with the admin account to a certain GeoNetwork
instance, but I do not recall ever changing the password. How can I reset (or
change) the admin password without logging on to the web interface?

Comment: Sometimes this error can be overcome by restarting the service. Are you still having problems after restarting the service?

Comment: Thanks nmtoken, after restarting the service I was able to log on again. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this error can be overcome by restarting the service